# Angular - return $modal promise and reject it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui

I'm trying to write a function which opens an angular-ui modal window and returns a promise once it's closed. This is normally easy, you ust return the modal instance, but in this scenario even if the window is closed property I want to check the response inside the .then() function and possibly reject the promise based on a status code, even though it has been successful.

That probably doesn't make much sense so here's some code...

```
// Function which should return a promise
var myFunc = function(){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'xxx',
        controller: 'yyy',
    });

    return modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {

        // If the login was successful then resolve
        if(result && result.success === true){

            // What goes here?

        }

        // If it was uncuccessful then reject, even though it was closed successfully.
        else{

            // What goes here?

        }


    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal was closed unsuccessfully');
    });


}


myFunc.then(function(){
    // DO something
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a new promise that will only get resolved if the promise from $modalInstance.result gets resolved AND your status code check is good. Something along the lines of:

```
var myFunc = function(){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'xxx',
        controller: 'yyy',
    });

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
        if (/* status code checks ok */) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            deferred.reject();
        }
    }, function() { 
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

See the [docs on $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I knew it would be something simple, the bit I hadn't worked out was the fact that you couldn't just return deferred.resolve() you have to return deferred.promise

Comment: I'm not clear on why that would work.  When I try the exact same code I get "ReferenceError: $modalInstance is not defined"

Comment: @ToddGrigsby Corrected a typo, $modalInstance should be modalInstance.